# 'package org.slf4j does not exist' despite spring-boot-starter in pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

In my pom.xml I have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And yet in Intellij it gives compilation errors
"package org.sfl4j does not exist"
"package org.springframework.breans.factor.annotation does not exist"

Why does this happen? It builds fine from the command line.

Comment: Does it help if you delete `.idea` directory and [reimport the project from pom.xml](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start)? Are there any errors in the Build | Sync tab after project is imported? Are there any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)?

Comment: Yes that did it, thanks a lot. Now there are no compile errors.

Comment: Please add your **full pom** not a snippet.